# Swift todo List change labeltext

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm making a todolist app in swift 3. So far I have this result : 
[image]

I can add a row, delete a row and when I click on a row it gives me this : 
[image]

The details is displayed in a Label, I'd like to be able to edit it when cliked on the label, like in a note app. Keeping the whole existing text and enable the user to add or erase things in it. I red that it is not possible to edit a label so I was wondering how is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Don't use a label - use a textfield or textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UILabel is used for content that you *don't* want to be editable.  Try using a [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview) here.